# Request from two tables with SUM

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL request:

```
SELECT U.*, SUM(P.cost) AS spent FROM `#__users` AS U LEFT JOIN `#__projects` AS P ON P.client_id = U.id WHERE 1=1 AND (spent >= 1000 AND spent < 2000) GROUP BY U.id ORDER BY U.user_creation_timestamp DESC LIMIT 25 OFFSET 0;
```

But I have error here:

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'spent' in 'where clause'
```

How can I fix the issue?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use alias in where and you can't filter aggregation function with where  for filter aggregation function you must use having

```
SELECT 
    U.*, 
    SUM(P.cost) AS spent 
FROM `#__users` AS U 
LEFT JOIN `#__projects` AS P ON P.client_id = U.id 
GROUP BY U.id 
HAVING  (SUM(P.cost)  >= 1000 AND SUM(P.cost)  < 2000) 
ORDER BY U.user_creation_timestamp DESC LIMIT 25 OFFSET 0;
```